# How do I removethe / at the end of every file in a sub-folder directory?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a new site, but have an Internal Server Error issue when I visit some pages through google.

I need to remove the / at the end of the url for it to work. At the moment I've wrote each rewrite rule to remove the / at the end like so:

```
RewriteRule lawn-care/north-yorkshire/ lawn-care/north-yorkshire [L,R]
RewriteRule lawn-care/edinburgh/ lawn-care/edinburgh [L,R]
RewriteRule lawn-care/croydon/ lawn-care/croydon [L,R]
```

Is there a way I can do this in 1 swoop? I only need to do this for files in the lawn-care folder.

Thank you.

```
Don't have much experience with htaccess files. So I'm not sure what to try as I'm not clear on what stuff like (.*) ^ $1 do.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, it is unclear what you are actually trying to do. If you want to change the links referring to those locations, then that is nothing rewriting can do. You need to change the logic that hands out those links.

If you want to rewrite incoming requests to those resources, then use a `RewriteRule` as you did, but I would expect that you want to implement an internal rewrite, not an external redirection, as you implemented it. So without the `R` flag.

And of course you can implement a single general rule if requests to all resources in that "directory" should get rewritten:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?lawn-care/(.+)/$ /lawn-care/$1 [L]
```

In general the best location for such rules is the central configuration of your http host. If you alternatively use a *distributed* configuration file (".htaccess"), although that really slows down the server. If you have to then take care that this file is readable for the http server process and that it is located inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of your http host.